# Bitmap differences between Windows versions

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, windows-xp, coded-ui-tests

As part of some automated testing, I'm using `UITestControl.CaptureImage()` to take screenshots of UI elements and compare them against expected results.  This worked fine and dandy in my Windows 7 environment but when I started running the tests on a Windows XP machine it would produce images that are somehow slightly different from Win7 images.  That is, they are pixel-for-pixel identical, but display other differences:

- Using a pixel-comparison tool verifies they are identical from a visual standpoint.
- The bitmap on XP is about twice as large as the Windows 7 bitmap.
- When compared in WinMerge there are obvious differences.

The code is quite simple:

```
public Image TakeWindowScreenshot()
{
    Image screenshot = null;
    screenshot = uiMapAds.TestApplication.UIItemWindow.UIItemImage.CaptureImage();
    return screenshot;
}

string pathToNewScreenshot = "C:\foo.bmp";
Image screenshot = TakeWindowScreenShot();
Bitmap screenshotBitmap = new Bitmap(screenshot);
screenshotBitmap.Save(pathToNewScreenshot);
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?  It also works fine in Windows 8, so XP is the outlier.  Another thing that might matter is that the Windows XP machine/OS is 32-bit while the others are 64, although all bitmaps are 32 BPP.

Comment: Calling it a .bmp file but actually saving it in the PNG format is one obvious serious mistake.  Compressed image formats are not necessarily identical, time and size are opposing goals.  XP also has an older GDI+ version.

Comment: @HansPassant can you elaborate on your response?  It would seem to me that the line `Bitmap screenshotBitmap = new Bitmap(screenshot);` creates a Bitmap object from the original Image object, not a PNG, but perhaps this is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Your Save() call is wrong, you don't use the overload that specifies the ImageFormat.  The default image format is PNG.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem.  It seems rather counterintuitive that the default format of Bitmap.Save() is not Bitmap, but there you have it.